# How to change the text of a button with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, button

Even though it should be pretty simple but for some reason, it's not working. Can someone tell me why?

In HTML I have created this button as:

```
<button id="T4">Hide</button>
```

And in jQuery I have created this function to change the text of the same button when it is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#T4").click(function() {
      $("#T4").prop('value', 'Show');
   });
});
```

Now what I'm trying to do is that, I have this button with text "Hide" and when it is clicked it changes it's text to "Show". Pretty simple right? But for somewhat reason it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `text()`:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#T4").click(function(){
       $("#T4").text('Show');
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly :)
However, someone also suggested to try `.html` so I actully went with that. But I tried your suggestion as well and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#T4").click(function(){
      $("#T4").html('show');
   });
});
```

I think you have to use html() to change the text of any element in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

simple, just use text(), because you're not input into value attribut

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#T4").click(function(){
      $("#T4").text('Show');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="T4">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this.

### Method 1:

Using `html()`.
Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#T4").click(function(){
      $("#T4").html("Show");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="T4">Hide</button>
```

### Method 2:

Using the `<input>` element instead of `<button>`.

Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#T4").click(function(){
      $("#T4").attr("value", "Show");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="T4" value="Hide">
```

### Method 3:

Using pure javascript (`innerHTML`).
Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#T4").click(function(){
      document.getElementById('T4').innerHTML = "Show";
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="T4">Hide</button>
```

And here is what you're trying to do (using `html()`):

```js
let bShow = true;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#T4").click(function(){
      if(bShow == true) {
        $("#T4").html("Show");
        bShow = false;
      } else if(bShow == false) {
        $("#T4").html("Hide");
        bShow = true;
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="T4">Hide</button>
```

A living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/zYvBMJR

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#T4").click(function(){
       $(this).text('Show');
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.